# finally versus atexit

Tags: python, exception, atexit

I end up having to write and support short python wrapper scripts with the following high-level structure:

```
try:
    code
    ...
    ...
except:
    raise
finally:
    file_handle.close()
    db_conn.close()
```

Notice that all I do in the `except` block is re-raise the exception **to the script caller** sans window-dressing; this is not a problem in my particular context. The idea here is that cleanup code should always be executed by means of the `finally` block, exception or not.

Am I better off using an `atexit` handler for this purpose? I could do without the extra level of indentation introduced by `try`.

Comment: If you're using a relatively new version of python you can use `with open('somefile') as file_handle:` instead of `try:`. It will automatically call `__exit__()` and close the file when it goes out of scope or hits an exception. It was added as [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: @Mike, thanks for the suggestion. However not all resources used in these programs have context managers available.

Comment: I think the `except:` clause is redundant, and you can leave it out.

Comment: @Keith, good point, noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `contextlib.closing`

```
with closing(resource1) as f1, closing(resource2) as f2:
    f1.something()
    f2.something()
```

And they will be automatically closed. Files objects can be used directly as contexts so you don't need the `closing` call.

If `close` is not the only method used by your resources, you can create custom functions with the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator.

Comment: thanks. Hoping against hope here - is there a way to get contextlib to work with argparse.FileType file handles?

Comment: @cravoori I think the `argparse.FileType` is just a class to open files as the user write a name. If the resulting object is just a normal file, it ca be used as a context manager. Something like `with parse_results.the_file:`

Comment: Anything that you close by calling `whatever.close()` can be wrapped with the `closing` context manager as shown above.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire, thank you. That useful insight clinches it for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

The `atexit` module provides a simple interface to register functions to be called when a program closes down normally. Functions registered are automatically executed upon normal interpreter termination.

```
import atexit

def cleanup():
    print 'performimg cleanup'

# multiple functions can be registered here...    
atexit.register(cleanup)
```

The sys module also provides a hook, sys.exitfunc, but only one function can be registered there.

`Finally` is  accompanied by `try except` block, functionality of `finally` can also be used for something similar like cleanup, however at `finally` block sys.exc_info is all-None.

If the finally clause raises another exception, the saved exception is discarded however you can put try except in the function registered with `atexit` to handle them.

Another `pro-con` is `atexit` functions are only executes when program terminates, however you can use `finally` (with try-except) anywhere in the code and perform the cleanup

In you scenario, where you want to raise an exception from cleanup content, usage of `atexit` would be helpful, if you are ok for cleanup to happen at the end of the program

Answer (score 1):

`atexit` is called upon program termination, so this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I need cleanup code to be run at program termination; if `atexit` is called upon program termination, sounds like it fits the bill?

Comment: in this case, then yes.  Most likely, all files and connections will be cleaned up by the OS for you, although this is certainly good practice to clean yourself.

Comment: @cravoori -- If you're no longer using a resource, I would advocate freeing it as soon as you no longer need it.  Who knows when you'll hit some OS limit for number of open file handles or whatever?

Comment: @mgilson, as a general principle, I agree. In  abnormal situations where say, a dbconnection throws an exception leading to program failure, I would like to be able to close any file handles that are open prior to exiting...something along the lines of `file_handle and file_handle.close()`

Comment: @cravoori: I think the point of using `finally` rather than `atexit` is that `atexit` is only called if the whole program closes. A `finally` block will be run whenever an exception occurs in that part of the code, even if that exception is caught and suppressed at a higher level.

Comment: @Blckknght, true. However, as noted in my post we are talking short wrapper scripts here. The code is at a single level.